With C++ meta programming, how to figure out whether you are in a class method or static/global function?
Is there a way to figure out whether the current scope is a global function/static class-method or a class-method?
I thought of the existence of this, but I'm unable to find a technique which doesn't error out during compilation when this does not exist.
I'd like to have one function-prototype which I can use in a member-method or global function, but it does behave differently. Without adding something to my classes and without adding additional arguments to my function call.
An example:
class NormalClass
{
public:
    void foo(int a, bool b)
    {
        DEBUG("print from class %d %d\n", a, b);
    }
};

void normal_function()
{
    DEBUG("print from a normal function");
}

Printing out
Class: print from class 1, 2
Global: print from a normal function


Can you give a code sample? The scope is going to be wherever you define the TMP at.

I added an example.

Would you be fine with passing the function as an additional argument, i.e. would debug(foo, "print from class %d %d\n", a, b); be ok?

This has to be a macro, since "the current scope" intended is the scope where the expression is evaluated. A regular function has no access to that scope, but a macro is literally expanded in that scope.

I should have added, that I don't want to have additional arguments to my function/macro DEBUG.

Maybe I'm missing something with the example but what difference does knowing the scope give you?  As is your DEBUG can be handled as a single macro/function.

Are you ok by adding MACRO inside your classes. (a la Q_OBJECT macro of Qt)?

@NathanOliver in my example, the difference is the prefix, in my real code, if I'm in a class, I check whether the class std::is_base_of a special class and I'm looking for member-variables to print if it is. At compile-time.

@Jarod42 no. No special class modification for my problem.

if I'm in a class, I check whether the class std::is_base_of a special class. So, you want to autodetect the class name of the current function scope, too?

@IgorG No. the the current class is derived from the "special" base class, I printing members of the special class, which I don't if I'm not a derived from or at global/static scope.

So, if all you need are some data members of the base class, then can't you just check whether those members are visible in the current scope? Would that be enough?

sounds like a XY problem. Detecting whether you are inside a special base class or not is a more specific, i believe simpler, problem to solve

@463035818_is_not_an_ai this problem is solved by using std::is_base_of. My questions focuses on the remaining problem which is whether I can use std::is_base_of or not. iow: Am I in a class-method or not.

@PatrickB. detecting whether you are inside a specific class or not is simpler than first detecting whether you can use std::base_of and then use that. See second half of my answer and NathanOlivers comment which points out that it can be done even nicer.

more specifically: It is much simpler to detect whether you are in one specifc class or not rather than detecting whether you are inside any class or not. The first is relatively simple, for the second I dont know a way that actually works

If the actual goal is to check whether some specific class data members are visible in the current scope (as clarified in the comments), then you can just declare the same variables in the global scope, but this time giving them a special unique type that can be used later to tell which variable is visible: global one or member one.
This approach is based on the fact that a member name will hide the name declared in the global or namespace scope.
Live example: https://godbolt.org/z/xaKK95WE9
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct TypeOfGlobalProbe;
static inline TypeOfGlobalProbe* memberName = nullptr;

#define DEBUG_IS_FREE() (std::is_same_v<decltype(memberName), TypeOfGlobalProbe*>)

void test_1()
{
    std::cout << "Is test_1() a free function? " << DEBUG_IS_FREE() << "\n";
}

struct Base
{
    int         memberName;
};

struct Derived : public Base
{
    void test_2()
    {
        std::cout << "Is test_2() a free function? " << DEBUG_IS_FREE() << "\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    test_1();
    Derived         d;
    d.test_2();
}

std::is_same_v<> is a compile-time check that can be used in, for example, if constexpr.

You can use std::source_location to get a string representing the function name. As far as I know this string is implementation defined though. With gcc it can be easily distinguished if the current scope is a free function, member or static member:
#include <source_location>
#include <iostream>

void check_member_or_static(std::source_location location  =
               std::source_location::current())
{
    std::cout << location.function_name() << "\n";
}

void free() {
    check_member_or_static();
}
struct foo {
    void member() {
        check_member_or_static();
    }
    static void statfun() {
        check_member_or_static();
    }
};

int main()
{
    free();
    foo{}.member();
    foo::statfun();
}

Output:
void free()
void foo::member()
static void foo::statfun()

PS: Only after writing this I realize that it looks like you want something at compile time. The above works at runtime only. Moreover, as pointed out in comments, foo::member does not distinguish a free function called member in namespace foo from the member function.

If you are either inside some base class or not the situation is much simpler. You can attach some key to the base. This key can be for example a type definition.
Credits goes to Raymond Chen from whom I stole the trait to check for completeness. The full article is found here.
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename, typename = void>
constexpr bool is_type_complete_v = false;

template<typename T>
constexpr bool is_type_complete_v
    <T, std::void_t<decltype(sizeof(T))>> = true;

#define inside_base is_type_complete_v<struct foobar>

struct base {

    private:
        struct foobar {};
};


void free() {
   std::cout << inside_base;
}
struct foo : base {
    void member() {
        std::cout << inside_base;
    }
    static void statfun() {
        std::cout << inside_base;
    }
};

int main()
{
    free();
    foo{}.member();
    foo::statfun();
}

Output:
011

When namelookup finds a foobar that is complete the macro evaluates to true, otherwise false. The actual definition can be private. A macro is used to introdue the forward declaration in case foobar is not in scope. The weak point is that the name has to be chosen such that it cannot be looked up elsewhere (which unfortunately has a similar smell as using macros but the effect is only local).

how about namespaces? https://godbolt.org/z/zP84axrWd I do not see a way to distinguish namespace and class/struct scope/

@MarekR good catch. I suppose std::source_location wasnt intended for this use case. Its a hack like it was already possible with good old __FUNCTION__.

"Only after writing this I realize that it looks like you want something at compile time." std::source_location might be used in constexpr.

"This key can be for example a type definition", A static bool is even simpler Demo unless I miss a point.

@Jarod42 your solution doesnt fit the "with metaprogramming" requirement :D. No, seriously, I suppose I was thinking much too complicated.
